# Does outlook out of office reply to junk mail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

Can you tell me, if you set your Out-of-Office, and then you get a Spam e-mail, will the Out-of-Office reply tell them that I exist and therefore subject me to a lot more Spam?

Answer (score 2):

Out of office will send a reply to any e-mail.  There are options in some versions to limit replies to only internal addreses or external.  As you do not mention the version, details for 2003-2010 follow.

For Microsoft Office Outlook 2010:
1.Make sure that you have a folder in the Exchange account’s message store selected.
NOTE: If you have other account types setup in the active Outlook profile, each account may have its own message store. If you do not have a folder contained within the Exchange account’s message store, the “Automatic Replies (Out of Office)” option will not be visible in step 3 later in this section.
2.Click the File tab, and then click the Info tab in the menu.
3.Click Automatic Replies (Out of Office).
Note If you do not see this option, you are not connected to an Exchange Server. For non exchange account user, visit the following Microsoft Website:
 Automatically reply to email messages without using an Exchange Server account

4.In the Automatic Replies dialog box, select the Send Automatic Replies check box.
5.If you want to specify a set time and date range, select the Only send during this time range check box. Then set the Start time, and then set the End time.
6.In the Inside my organization tab, type the message that you want to send within your organization, and in the Outside my organization tab, type the message that you want to send outside your organization.
7.Click OK.
8.If you selected the “Only send during this time range” option in step 4, the Automatic Replies (Out of Office) feature will continue to run until the date and time set for the End Time in step 5 is reached.
Otherwise, the Automatic Replies (Out of Office) will continue to run until you repeat step 1 and select the “Do not send automatic replies” option.

For Microsoft Office Outlook 2007:1.On the Tools menu, click Out of Office Assistant….
2.In the Out of Office Assistant dialog box, select the Send Out of Office auto-replies check box.
3.If you want to specify a set time and date range, select the Only send during this time range check box. Then set the Start time, and then set the End time.
4.In the Inside my organization tab, type the message that you want to send within your organization, and in the Outside my organization tab, type the message that you want to send outside your organization.
5.Click OK.
6.If you selected the “Only send during this time range” option in step 4, the Out of Office Assistant feature will continue to run until the date and time set for the End Time in step 5 is reached.
Otherwise, the Out of Office Assistant will continue to run until you repeat step 1 and select the “Do not send Out of Office auto-replies” option.

For Microsoft Office Outlook 2003:
1.On the Tools menu, click Out of Office Assistant….
2.In the Out of Office Assistant dialog box, click I am currently Out of the Office.
3.In the AutoReply only once to each sender with the following text box, type the message that you want to send while you are out of the office.
4.Click OK.
5.The Out of Office Assistant will continue to run until you repeat step 1 and select the “I am currently In the Office” option.